# Combine object properties into a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have properties num1, num2, num3 on objectX.  I want to take a list of objectX and create a single list of integers populated with the num1, num2, num3 values.

Here's an example using System.Drawing.Point:

```
Point p1 = new Point(1,2);
Point p2 = new Point(3,4);

var points = new[] { p1, p2 };
var combined = points.SelectMany(a => new[] {a.X, a.Y});
```

Is this the most readable way of doing this?  The syntax feels a bit fiddly to me.  Could you do it with a [LINQ Query expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)?

**FYI** using LBushkin's query expression in this example would look like this:

```
var combined = from p in points
    let values = new[] {p.X, p.Y}
    from x in values
    select x;
```

I'll leave it an exercise for the reader to decide which is more readable.

Comment: Uh, that __is__ a linq expression already

Comment: I sense an underlying problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: correction: LINQ Query expression http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx

Comment: @TesterTurnedDeveloper, you are technically correct.  But it is a reality that LINQ is now *also* synonymous with lambda-based Enumerable/Queryable methods.  For better or worse.

Comment: re:underlying problem - it's just a 'challenge' i've set myself while learning LINQ.

Comment: @Jonas: Might be a "challenge" for OP, but exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is an example where I would probably use query syntax with LINQ:**

```
var result = from item in someList
             let values = new int[]{ item.A, item.B, item.C, ... }
             from x in values
             select x;
```

Using a custom iterator (as Kirk demonstrates) may be more efficient, since it doesn't require allocating the temporary array - but the CLR is relatively good at recycling short-lived objects, so in practice this is rarely an issue.

Comment: It's no more powerful yet dramatically more verbose than the OP's original example...

Comment: @Kirk: I don't disagree. However, I would say that expressing queries *as queries* can be useful. Depending on how it's used, `SelectMany` can obscure what the intent of the logic behind awkward lambda syntax.

Comment: heh, yeah, though from where I sit, LINQ obscures the intent of the logic behind ackward query syntax. ;)  But I realize this gets into religious warfare-zone, so I'll stop.

Answer (score 7):

I think cleanest would be if ObjectX had a property to combine your num properties, let's call it Numbers:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Numbers 
{
    get
    {
        yield return Num1;
        yield return Num2;
        yield return Num3;
    }
}
```

Now whenever you have acecss to an ObjectX, you can easily interrogate it's number properties, allowing you to do:

```
var combined = objectXs.SelectMany(a => a.Numbers);
```