# aggregate two objects in a list into one

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which consist of object.

```
List<Person> where 

class Person
{
    enum id;
    string name;
    int goals;

}
```

Record 1: `{enum.1,"Mark",20}`
Record 2: `{enum.1,"Mark",7 }`

End Result: Only one record `{enum.1,"Mark",27}`

I have same person's record multiple times in database with different goals.
I know I can use SQL function.
I am trying to find a linq query.

I want to aggregate two

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910222/combine-object-properties-into-a-list-with-linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from person in PersonList
group person by new { id = person.id, name = person.name } into grouping
select new Person
{
    id = grouping.Key.id,
    name = grouping.Key.name,
    goals = grouping.Sum(x => x.goals)
}
```

A grouping would work.

Comment: +1 Beat me by 29 seconds with almost exactly the same thing :)

Comment: @lc. actually your answer was compilable :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, you could have edited it or pointed out the flaw.

Comment: @Joe I also could downvote it. But actually I hoped lc will undelete his answer - it was compilable, with some explanations, and nice group key creation. BTW nice rule of thumb - use short variable names in short scopes.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you are very special to me. I hope someday to meet your standards.

Comment: @Joe not mine standards - [his](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin). I bet you will be glad to meet those standards someday